Polars Pivot treats null values as 0 when summing
I have this code:
import polars as pl

pl.DataFrame({
    'label':   ['AA', 'CC', 'BB', 'AA', 'CC'],
    'account': ['EU', 'US', 'US', 'EU', 'EU'],
    'qty':     [1.5,  43.2, None, None, 18.9]})\
  .pivot('account', index='label', aggregate_function='sum')

which gives
shape: (3, 3)
┌───────┬──────┬──────┐
│ label ┆ EU   ┆ US   │
│ ---   ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ str   ┆ f64  ┆ f64  │
╞═══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ AA    ┆ 1.5  ┆ null │
│ CC    ┆ 18.9 ┆ 43.2 │
│ BB    ┆ null ┆ 0.0  │
└───────┴──────┴──────┘

Now, when there are any null values in the original data, I want the pivot table to show null in the respective cell. However, AA-EU shows 1.5 (but should be null), and BB-US shows 0.0 (but should also be null).
I tried using
aggregate_function=lambda col: pl.when(col.has_nulls())\
                                 .then(pl.lit(None, dtype=pl.Float64))\
                                 .otherwise(pl.sum(col))

but it errors out with AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '_pyexpr'.
How can I fix this?

You can use a Polars expression as an aggregate function:
df.pivot('account', index='label', aggregate_function=
    pl.when(~pl.element().has_nulls()).then(pl.element().sum()))


shape: (3, 3)
┌───────┬──────┬──────┐
│ label ┆ EU   ┆ US   │
│ ---   ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ str   ┆ f64  ┆ f64  │
╞═══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ AA    ┆ null ┆ null │
│ CC    ┆ 18.9 ┆ 43.2 │
│ BB    ┆ null ┆ null │
└───────┴──────┴──────┘

